# How to store text that is to be displayed in an android application?

Tags: android, sqlite

I know C and C++ and I am now trying to develop android applications. I learnt the basics and I am trying to create an educational android application, which gives some theory on the topic and allows users to take a objective test.

Now to do this, how to store the theory information? I think SQLite can be used for quiz as I plan to add a question, 3 options for correct answer and the actual correct answer in a table and match user responses to score the test.

Is the approach correct? and I don't think this is not the right idea for theory part. Should i hardcode in the textview or should I use file IO?

Please throw some light.

Comment: Never hardcode text. Use SQLite.

Comment: SQLite is the best option as you can manipulate your view and data as an how you want it. Hardcode text is not a good habbit

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should use database for this. You can store in one table question and in second answers.

Comment: I need to know how to store long text part of theory. This is not the info to store in a table right?

Comment: You can also store long text in database. Its no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

The suggested way is to make a DB in Sqlite. It is used to keep small sized data locally in phone instead of storing in server.

A very good example to Create table/store data, Update the data on SQlite is explained here [link](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/sqlite-crud-example-in-android-activeandroid/)

Answer (score 0):

```
TopicMaster
+-----------------------------+
|TopicId, Number Primary Key  |
|TopicName, Text              |
|ParentTopicId, Number        |
+-----------------------------+


ContentMaster
+-----------------------------+
|ContentId, Number Primary Key|
|TopicId, Number Foreign Key  |
|Content, Text                |
+-----------------------------+
```

Use this kind of structure, modify it according to your need. In this structure you can have topics, subtopics. And this will keep your content from getting long.

From [here](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html)

> The current implementation will only support a string or BLOB length up to 2^31-1 or 2147483647

So, if your content doesn't go beyond this limit. No worries.

Answer (score 0):

For storing values there are couple of ways

1. By using Database
2. By using shared preference
3. Save Value in Json and build text file and store it locally

and many more

but by using database be the best way to do that